# cast from row to string (mysqli fetch_array)

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I have a mysqli query that I want to convert to json.

tried:

```
$myArray = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $myArray[] = $row;
}
$ot = json_encode($myArray);
print_r($ot);
```

but got no results (blank line). If I print_r $myArray, there are values.

I can print out correct values on the while loop, so made another array and tried to add them, but neither of the following worked:

```
$mA []=array (alumnoX => $al1, grupox=> "two");
$mA []=array (alumnoX => (string)$al1, grupox=> "two");
$mA []=array (alumnoX => strval($al1), grupox=> "two");
$mA []=array (alumnoX => $row['alumno'], grupox=> "two");
```

How can I fix this?

edit -- 
(print_r of $myArray)

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
              [0] => Martín 
              [alumno] => Martín 
              [1] => 1A 
              [grupo] => 1A 
              [2] => Computación básica 
              [materia] => Computación básica 
              [3] => sala cómputo cs 01 
              [salon] => sala cómputo cs 01 
              ) 
     [1] => Array ( 
              [0] => Martín 
              [alumno] => Martín 
              [1] => 1A 
              [grupo] => 1A 
              [2] => Introducción a la música 
              [materia] => Introducción a la música 
              [3] => Auditorio [salon] => Auditorio 
              ) 
      )
```

Comment: do me a favour put the actual result of a `print_r()` into your question rather than an edited version

Comment: Can you post the results for `var_dump($myArray);`

Comment: var_dump:

array(2) { [0]=> array(8) { [0]=> string(7) "Martín " ["alumno"]=> string(7) "Martín " [1]=> string(2) "1A" ["grupo"]=> string(2) "1A" [2]=> string(18) "Computación básica" ["materia"]=> string(18) "Computación básica" [3]=> string(18) "sala cómputo cs 01" ["salon"]=> string(18) "sala cómputo cs 01" } [1]=> array(8) { [0]=> string(7) "Martín " ["alumno"]=> string(7) "Martín " [1]=> string(2) "1A" ["grupo"]=> string(2) "1A" [2]=> string(24) "Introducción a la música" ["materia"]=> string(24) "Introducción a la música" [3]=> string(9) "Auditorio" ["salon"]=> string(9) "Auditorio" } }

Comment: Thanks, will use var_export form now on.

Answer (score 0):

When using `mysqli_fetch_array()` will return an associative array and a numerically indexed array, which will duplicate all columns and confuse you and the json object. So use either `mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)` or `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` so you only get the more useful associative array returned.

```
// assume you have code something like this
$result = mysql_query($con, $sql);
if ( ! $result ) {
    echo mysqli_error($con);
    exit;
}


$myArray = array();

//while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    $myArray[] = $row;
}
$ot = json_encode($myArray);

//print_r($ot); print_r() works on arrays and $ot is now a string
echo "<pre>$ot</pre>";
```

Comment: Thanks Riggs, unfortunately I only get a blank line. Connection is working fine, var_export is very similar to previous result.

Comment: Hmm well it looks like it should work, have you checked your `php error log`

Comment: Woops, missed the `print_r($ot)`... change that to a simple echo as per my amended code as `print_r` displays arrays and `$ot` is a string

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately still a blank line. Error log doesn't has anything in there.

Comment: You have only shown a small amount of code, is this returning the JSON string to an AJAX call or just showing it on the web page

Comment: At this moment just trying to display in web page. Final intention is to display it in a table called by ajax. Previous code is only the connection settings and query.

Comment: Try the amended echo then, maybe where you are echoing it in the page is obsquiring it, also try looking at the `page source` from you browser to see it it is there but not shoowing because its inside some other HTML tag that is obsquiring it

Comment: Tried without luck to make a new file. With the var_export output I can actually make the json_encode and it is fine, however the one from the query isn't working. Thank you for your help Riggs, will try another machine tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

The data had some none conventional characters in it, after replacing:

```
json_encode($myArray );
```

to:

```
json_encode($myArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
```

It worked as expected.